# Wait for event in async method

Tags: c#

I'm using the WebsocketSharp library for accessing to a websocket sever on a ESP32.
When the websocket client sends a message to the server, this method in the server gets called, for example to get the device info data:

```
void onWsEvent(AsyncWebSocket * server, AsyncWebSocketClient * client, AwsEventType type, void * arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len){    

    if(type == WS_EVT_DATA){
      Log.notice("Websocket data received" CR);     

      if(jsonDecoder.GetMessageType(stringData) == "RequestGetDeviceInfo"){
          auto msg = jsonDecoder.CreateDeviceInfoMessage(
          //Create json with the data, and "MessageType" is "DeviceInfo"
          );          
      //here the request gets an answer
          socket.text(client ->id(),msg);
      }
    }      
}
```

On the client, there is the pattern that either something gets sent, or an event is triggered with the received data. So when a json message is sent with the MessageType "RequestDeviceInfo", the event will be triggered:

```
using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.178.34/ws"))
{
   var msg = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Message()
   {
       MessageType = "RequestDeviceInfo",
   });


   ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
   {
       //e.Data contains the json with MessageType "DeviceInfo"
       string jsonAnswer = e.Data;
   };

}
```

So if the Request is sent, the event will trigger 100% with the json response.
My question is: how can I pack that in a "get" method (ideally with a timeout)? Like:

```
async DeviceInfo GetDeviceInfo()
{
           //Send the request and wait for the event and return the e.Data 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, `socket.text(client ->id(),msg);` isn't valid C#

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/interop-with-other-asynchronous-patterns-and-types#tasks-and-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap) provides a clear pattern for turning EAP (event based asynchrony) into TAP (task based asynchrony). It should be easy to fit the pattern to your needs.

Comment: @spender That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!